# Bluetooth with AR9285 not working

Tags: 15.04, bluetooth

I was searching the forum and google but being new to Ubuntu I'm not sure which way to go and didn't recognize the right answer.

I'm on Ubuntu 15.04 with Gnome and new to Linux at all.
I have an *Acer Aspire R7 571G* with an *Atheros AR9285 wireless adapter* which supports both WLAN and Bluetooth.
WLAN is working just great right after installing Ubuntu.
In the system settings the bluetooth icon is visible but everything is greyed out.
I'm also unable to geht any information about the bluetooth adapter from the system.
There is no physical switch but the functions button.

What I tried:

**lsusb**:

```
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 006: ID 0483:91d1 STMicroelectronics 
Bus 003 Device 005: ID 04f3:005a Elan Microelectronics Corp. 
Bus 003 Device 004: ID 064e:e330 Suyin Corp. 
Bus 003 Device 003: ID 046d:c526 Logitech, Inc. Nano Receiver
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0b95:772b ASIX Electronics Corp. AX88772B
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

**rfkill list**:

```
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
Soft blocked: no
Hard blocked: no
```

**lsmod**:

```
Module                  Size  Used by
bluetooth             491520  0 
pci_stub               16384  1 
vboxpci                24576  0 
vboxnetadp             28672  0 
vboxnetflt             28672  0 
vboxdrv               421888  3 vboxnetadp,vboxnetflt,vboxpci
binfmt_misc            20480  1 
asix                   40960  0 
usbnet                 45056  1 asix
mii                    16384  2 asix,usbnet
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     53248  1 
hid_sensor_incl_3d     16384  0 
hid_sensor_gyro_3d     16384  0 
hid_sensor_magn_3d     16384  0 
hid_sensor_als         16384  0 
snd_hda_codec_realtek    86016  1 
hid_sensor_rotation    16384  0 
hid_sensor_accel_3d    16384  0 
snd_hda_codec_generic    69632  1 snd_hda_codec_realtek
hid_sensor_trigger     16384  12 hid_sensor_gyro_3d,hid_sensor_incl_3d,hid_sensor_accel_3d,hid_sensor_rotation,hid_sensor_als,hid_sensor_magn_3d
industrialio_triggered_buffer    16384  6 hid_sensor_gyro_3d,hid_sensor_incl_3d,hid_sensor_accel_3d,hid_sensor_rotation,hid_sensor_als,hid_sensor_magn_3d
kfifo_buf              16384  1 industrialio_triggered_buffer
industrialio           57344  9 hid_sensor_trigger,hid_sensor_gyro_3d,industrialio_triggered_buffer,hid_sensor_incl_3d,hid_sensor_accel_3d,hid_sensor_rotation,hid_sensor_als,kfifo_buf,hid_sensor_magn_3d
hid_sensor_iio_common    16384  6 hid_sensor_gyro_3d,hid_sensor_incl_3d,hid_sensor_accel_3d,hid_sensor_rotation,hid_sensor_als,hid_sensor_magn_3d
snd_hda_intel          32768  3 
snd_hda_controller     32768  1 snd_hda_intel
uvcvideo               90112  0 
snd_hda_codec         143360  5 snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_controller
snd_hwdep              20480  1 snd_hda_codec
videobuf2_vmalloc      16384  1 uvcvideo
snd_pcm               106496  4 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_controller
intel_rapl             20480  0 
videobuf2_memops       16384  1 videobuf2_vmalloc
iosf_mbi               16384  1 intel_rapl
x86_pkg_temp_thermal    16384  0 
intel_powerclamp       20480  0 
arc4                   16384  2 
coretemp               16384  0 
videobuf2_core         49152  1 uvcvideo
v4l2_common            16384  1 videobuf2_core
kvm_intel             151552  0 
kvm                   483328  1 kvm_intel
crct10dif_pclmul       16384  0 
hid_sensor_hub         20480  8 hid_sensor_trigger,hid_sensor_gyro_3d,hid_sensor_incl_3d,hid_sensor_accel_3d,hid_sensor_rotation,hid_sensor_als,hid_sensor_magn_3d,hid_sensor_iio_common
crc32_pclmul           16384  0 
ghash_clmulni_intel    16384  0 
hid_multitouch         20480  0 
snd_seq_midi           16384  0 
videodev              159744  3 uvcvideo,v4l2_common,videobuf2_core
ath9k                 147456  0 
snd_seq_midi_event     16384  1 snd_seq_midi
media                  24576  2 uvcvideo,videodev
ath9k_common           32768  1 ath9k
snd_rawmidi            32768  1 snd_seq_midi
ath9k_hw              458752  2 ath9k_common,ath9k
nouveau              1400832  1 
aesni_intel           172032  0 
ath                    32768  3 ath9k_common,ath9k,ath9k_hw
aes_x86_64             20480  1 aesni_intel
lrw                    16384  1 aesni_intel
gf128mul               16384  1 lrw
snd_seq                69632  2 snd_seq_midi_event,snd_seq_midi
mac80211              724992  1 ath9k
glue_helper            16384  1 aesni_intel
i915                 1052672  4 
ablk_helper            16384  1 aesni_intel
cryptd                 20480  3 ghash_clmulni_intel,aesni_intel,ablk_helper
snd_seq_device         16384  3 snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq_midi
snd_timer              32768  2 snd_pcm,snd_seq
serio_raw              16384  0 
mxm_wmi                16384  1 nouveau
cfg80211              540672  4 ath,ath9k_common,ath9k,mac80211
ttm                    98304  1 nouveau
rtsx_pci_ms            20480  0 
drm_kms_helper        122880  2 i915,nouveau
memstick               20480  1 rtsx_pci_ms
lpc_ich                24576  0 
drm                   344064  9 ttm,i915,drm_kms_helper,nouveau
snd                    90112  17 snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hwdep,snd_timer,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_pcm,snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel,snd_seq_device
soundcore              16384  2 snd,snd_hda_codec
i2c_algo_bit           16384  2 i915,nouveau
mei_me                 20480  0 
shpchp                 40960  0 
mei                    90112  1 mei_me
joydev                 20480  0 
wmi                    20480  2 mxm_wmi,nouveau
video                  20480  2 i915,nouveau
mac_hid                16384  0 
parport_pc             32768  0 
ppdev                  20480  0 
lp                     20480  0 
parport                45056  3 lp,ppdev,parport_pc
autofs4                40960  2 
hid_generic            16384  0 
usbhid                 53248  0 
hid                   110592  4 hid_multitouch,hid_generic,hid_sensor_hub,usbhid
rtsx_pci_sdmmc         24576  0 
psmouse               118784  0 
ahci                   36864  2 
libahci                32768  1 ahci
rtsx_pci               49152  2 rtsx_pci_ms,rtsx_pci_sdmmc
```

Any ideas what I can do to make my bluetooth work?
Thanks in advance!

---

Here is additional information from the acer support what is in manufactured in my Laptop depending on the serial no.:

Liteon 3rd WiFi 2x2 AGN+ BT4.0 Broadcom 43228+20702 (WiFi 43228 2x2 DB AGN+BT4.0 20702)

Further help is appreciated.

Comment: have you tried going to Ubuntu software center/edit/additionaldrivers/ try this and post your results. or in the terminal type `sudo modprobe ath9k
` otherwise next step is to try and install missing firmware

Comment: What is the model number of the wifi card and does the card have 2 stickers with MAC addresses on them?  The model number of the card should be similar to AR5B???

Comment: modprobe is giving me no result.
Because the card is nowhere to find I'm not sure if the drivers are installed correctly. But the vendor description says that the laptop has a bluetooth adapter installed.

The model number is ATH-AR5B95ath-ar5b95

Comment: The model number is ATH-AR5B95
There is no MAC address mentioned but it has two antennas connected a black and a white wire

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -nn` terminal command. And please do not post additional information as answers. This is not a forum.

Answer (score 1):

Your AR5B95 does not include a bluetooth chipset, the AR5B195 is the card with the same AR9285 wifi with bluetooth

Comment: I have ordered the Laptop two years ago, here is the description:
http://www.notebooksbilliger.de/product_info.php/products_id/121729
The detailed product number is:
Acer Aspire R7-571G-53338G75ass
And therefore it is mentioned to have Bluetooth.
Ok, I'm looking for the wrong adapter, is there another adapter for Bluetooth?
There is another info on the wireless card:
aw-ne 785h

Comment: Your `lsusb` results show nothing that appears to be a bluetooth device.  My wifi bluetooth combo card is [AW-NB037H](https://wikidevi.com/wiki/AzureWave_AW-NB037H)